# Disable inactive window dimming

Tags: gnome, 19.04

Since updating to 19.04 I've noticed that inactive windows are dimmed when they are not focussed. I am using the Yaru-Dark theme.

As someone who uses dual monitors, this behaviour is a complete pain. I don't want the document on the left monitor to suddenly dim because I'm actively using a window on the right monitor.

Example:

Focussed: [image]

Inactive: [image]

Notice the PDF background is grey.

How can I turn this off?

Comment: FWIW: The only GNOME Shell Extension enabled on my system is "Desktop Icons".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to be a feature in the Yaru theme: https://github.com/ubuntu/yaru/issues/212

It is unclear if this behaviour can be disabled.

Comment: Just a suggestion: try Adwaita Dark. You may like it or not.

Comment: I used to use Adwaita Dark on my previous box - definitely a nice theme. It's a bit of a shame though, because I like Yaru otherwise..

Comment: You maybe interested to read about how (some) GNOME developers view themes other than their own: https://stopthemingmy.app/

Comment: In my Ubuntu 18.04 all themes seem to have this dimming effect. No idea how to turn it off, it's VERY annoying.